# Continue Running batch from disconnected source location

Tags: windows, command-line, usb, batch-file

I have a batch file running on from USB drive. 
The batch file contains a command that unmounts the drive, but after that command I want to execute more commands which dont get executed after its unmounted.

important notes:
I do not want to create a second batch file manually somewhere stored locally. A automatically generated temporarily one would do the work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ECHO command to create a batchfile in temp folder:

```
ECHO command_one some parameter >> %temp%\mytempfile.bat
```

And to run the created file:

```
%temp%\mytempfile.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create anything locally, then what you're looking to do isn't possible. You can't run commands in a batch file from a drive that has been unmounted.

Florian's solution however, would work, and you could add some simple script to delete itself when finished.